# Remove tab bar from app design and add a "home screen" storyboard

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I have a tab bar based iOS app, and I would like to change it. I don't need the tab bar controller; instead I would like to have a home screen with a list view and big icons for the modules of the app, which are represented by tabs right now.

How can I change it without creating a new project? I created the home screen view in a storyboard and set it to the main story board in info.plist, but it won't load the new screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make the new home screen view controller the *entry point* for this storyboard. Make sure it has the "Entry Point" arrow or its "Initial view controller" checkbox is checked.

Also, make sure your app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunching:` has no code except for `return true`. You want the storyboard to do all the configuration automatically at launch.

Comment: Thank you. I tried all that, but i got this exception,  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationViewController tabBar]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: That seems to mean you used a navigation controller instead of a tab bar controller but you continued to use code that tries to say `tabBar:` to that navigation controller. However, _that is not what you asked_. I'm sorry you are having a new problem, but that's not the point; the point is whether you are now loading your new home screen, as you asked to do. If so, I've answered the question you asked. If not, it's because something else is going on of which you have told us nothing whatever (where are you even saying `tabBar` now?) I'm a programmer, not a mind-reader.

Comment: I am sorry if this confused you and i really appreciate your help. I am not using tabbar anywhere in my code, but when I make the changes and run the app i get this exception right after the launch screen.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake on my end. I had method which should update the badge count on tab and it was causing the exception. Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm not confused, I assure you.